# Calculated blockhash of PoA block mismatches with actual blockhash returned by RPC

Tags: go-ethereum, parity, json-rpc, poa, rlp

I set up a Demo PoA chain using Parity Etheruem. I sent some transactions to it and it started producing blocks. A block on my demo PoA chain was generated with block hash `0x41055969db3b40fd07ef1374353c051f9f24f3aff806186b1e9d134f01d8467a`.

To verify, when I used block headers to calculate the block hash using the standard procedure, it resulted in a different blockhash. If used the same procedure to calculate blockhash of an ETH mainnet block, it matches exactly.

I have created a github repository for calculating block hash:

```
git clone https://github.com/zemse/tx-proof.git
cd tx-proof
npm i
node blockHash.js
```

Script for calculating blockhash:

```
const { Header } = require('eth-object');
const { keccak, encode } = require('eth-util-lite');
const Rpc  = require('isomorphic-rpc');

// A Parity PoA chain block
const rpc = new Rpc('http://13.127.185.136:80');
const inputBlockHash = '0x41055969db3b40fd07ef1374353c051f9f24f3aff806186b1e9d134f01d8467a';

// A recent Ethereum mainnet block
// const rpc = new Rpc('https://mainnet.infura.io');
// const inputBlockHash = '0x3419812fd8adad94cc4162ff852ac8b9543186398049f4ed0a2c8ae928589193';

(async() => {
    let rpcBlock = await rpc.eth_getBlockByHash(inputBlockHash, true);
    console.log('RPC block', rpcBlock);

    const blockHeader = Header.fromRpc(rpcBlock);
    console.log('block header', blockHeader);

    const rlpEncodedBlock = encode(blockHeader);
    console.log('rlp encoded block', rlpEncodedBlock);

    const calculatedBlockHash = '0x'+(keccak(rlpEncodedBlock)).toString('hex');
    console.log('blockHash', calculatedBlockHash);

    console.log(inputBlockHash === calculatedBlockHash ? 'Matching' : 'Mismatching');
})();
```

Output of the above code:

```
$ node blockhash.js 
RPC block { author: '0x08d85bd1004e3e674042eaddf81fb3beb4853a22',
  difficulty: '0xffffffffffffffffffffffffed3a8006',
  extraData:
   '0xde830207008f5061726974792d457468657265756d86312e33392e30826c69',
  gasLimit: '0x5ba462',
  gasUsed: '0xa410',
  hash:
   '0x41055969db3b40fd07ef1374353c051f9f24f3aff806186b1e9d134f01d8467a',
  logsBloom:
   '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
  miner: '0x08d85bd1004e3e674042eaddf81fb3beb4853a22',
  number: '0x1',
  parentHash:
   '0xeaf8c607b36ff7b805f03fdca8f90721d9669c5f3ed53479f62a00ba7211f646',
  receiptsRoot:
   '0xd95b673818fa493deec414e01e610d97ee287c9421c8eff4102b1647c1a184e4',
  sealFields:
   [ '0x8412c57ff9',
     '0xb8416a7affb843a5021a5985e82772658dcf469b2faeac97b19c1d97f6ed9234c06c12988916a0555477ae96792246325b02840aecccbdb7854667d43272c88e3ca601' ],
  sha3Uncles:
   '0x1dcc4de8dec75d7aab85b567b6ccd41ad312451b948a7413f0a142fd40d49347',
  signature:
   '6a7affb843a5021a5985e82772658dcf469b2faeac97b19c1d97f6ed9234c06c12988916a0555477ae96792246325b02840aecccbdb7854667d43272c88e3ca601',
  size: '0x328',
  stateRoot:
   '0x2bf95643a5a2e92df933f744f697cb3db45b65a2ab96421ab056e3ed9bbf6e87',
  step: '314933241',
  timestamp: '0x5ddb7fdd',
  totalDifficulty: '0xffffffffffffffffffffffffed3c8006',
  transactions:
   [ { blockHash:
        '0x41055969db3b40fd07ef1374353c051f9f24f3aff806186b1e9d134f01d8467a',
       blockNumber: '0x1',
       chainId: null,
       condition: null,
       creates: null,
       from: '0xc8e1f3b9a0cdfcef9ffd2343b943989a22517b26',
       gas: '0x7530',
       gasPrice: '0x4a817c800',
       hash:
        '0x69d8f874bd03f8f745d22510fbcfefb47f78ee25b35087f924ba93fe13111fcc',
       input: '0x',
       nonce: '0x0',
       publicKey:
        '0x39277413da2ed02bf599b9a0047495d9a23afcadb25a11b02ac9e27e61c2c5775fb744aea60f2f9d2b873650cbe8b0d1a7631886418467e869c0c2465f5082e5',
       r:
        '0x8e9e2d149c38864da8df0300c292beeac1070b31ac4ef3820f8bbb46d4039105',
       raw:
        '0xf86c808504a817c80082753094d5dd476de0a26adb8069fc36537ab3a6b85192a4880de0b6b3a7640000801ca08e9e2d149c38864da8df0300c292beeac1070b31ac4ef3820f8bbb46d4039105a04875548fe280b25c01471028f9a91609e31541ce658e35368905ea798b86fa47',
       s:
        '0x4875548fe280b25c01471028f9a91609e31541ce658e35368905ea798b86fa47',
       standardV: '0x1',
       to: '0xd5dd476de0a26adb8069fc36537ab3a6b85192a4',
       transactionIndex: '0x0',
       v: '0x1c',
       value: '0xde0b6b3a7640000' },
     { blockHash:
        '0x41055969db3b40fd07ef1374353c051f9f24f3aff806186b1e9d134f01d8467a',
       blockNumber: '0x1',
       chainId: null,
       condition: null,
       creates: null,
       from: '0xc8e1f3b9a0cdfcef9ffd2343b943989a22517b26',
       gas: '0x7530',
       gasPrice: '0x4a817c800',
       hash:
        '0x4df75c768e659962ca542b9fb964e8b5cd29c074becb4efb38722d232060e9c5',
       input: '0x',
       nonce: '0x1',
       publicKey:
        '0x39277413da2ed02bf599b9a0047495d9a23afcadb25a11b02ac9e27e61c2c5775fb744aea60f2f9d2b873650cbe8b0d1a7631886418467e869c0c2465f5082e5',
       r:
        '0xf8035510b07e57ca38595ef947baf11e959de356ae16bf9c43be6d22f0b9b76e',
       raw:
        '0xf86c018504a817c80082753094d5dd476de0a26adb8069fc36537ab3a6b85192a4880de0b6b3a7640000801ca0f8035510b07e57ca38595ef947baf11e959de356ae16bf9c43be6d22f0b9b76ea053e53deff593103755ebbb74da1e53048edce6fe3c00161935dbb3e2aa4d2da2',
       s:
        '0x53e53deff593103755ebbb74da1e53048edce6fe3c00161935dbb3e2aa4d2da2',
       standardV: '0x1',
       to: '0xd5dd476de0a26adb8069fc36537ab3a6b85192a4',
       transactionIndex: '0x1',
       v: '0x1c',
       value: '0xde0b6b3a7640000' } ],
  transactionsRoot:
   '0x89a8e66c754222830247e2f5d74d6a4a2a9ae751f96a76cd9ba1ab64daf3d3ce',
  uncles: [] }
block header Header [
  <Buffer ea f8 c6 07 b3 6f f7 b8 05 f0 3f dc a8 f9 07 21 d9 66 9c 5f 3e d5 34 79 f6 2a 00 ba 72 11 f6 46>,
  <Buffer 1d cc 4d e8 de c7 5d 7a ab 85 b5 67 b6 cc d4 1a d3 12 45 1b 94 8a 74 13 f0 a1 42 fd 40 d4 93 47>,
  <Buffer 08 d8 5b d1 00 4e 3e 67 40 42 ea dd f8 1f b3 be b4 85 3a 22>,
  <Buffer 2b f9 56 43 a5 a2 e9 2d f9 33 f7 44 f6 97 cb 3d b4 5b 65 a2 ab 96 42 1a b0 56 e3 ed 9b bf 6e 87>,
  <Buffer 89 a8 e6 6c 75 42 22 83 02 47 e2 f5 d7 4d 6a 4a 2a 9a e7 51 f9 6a 76 cd 9b a1 ab 64 da f3 d3 ce>,
  <Buffer d9 5b 67 38 18 fa 49 3d ee c4 14 e0 1e 61 0d 97 ee 28 7c 94 21 c8 ef f4 10 2b 16 47 c1 a1 84 e4>,
  <Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ... 206 more bytes>,
  <Buffer ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ed 3a 80 06>,
  <Buffer 01>,
  <Buffer 5b a4 62>,
  <Buffer a4 10>,
  <Buffer 5d db 7f dd>,
  <Buffer de 83 02 07 00 8f 50 61 72 69 74 79 2d 45 74 68 65 72 65 75 6d 86 31 2e 33 39 2e 30 82 6c 69>,
  <Buffer >,
  <Buffer > ]
rlp encoded block <Buffer f9 01 fd a0 ea f8 c6 07 b3 6f f7 b8 05 f0 3f dc a8 f9 07 21 d9 66 9c 5f 3e d5 34 79 f6 2a 00 ba 72 11 f6 46 a0 1d cc 4d e8 de c7 5d 7a ab 85 b5 67 b6 ... 462 more bytes>
blockHash 0xbced55679c03b96a7644dbf808be459e61be26a9389e6ee6000c0a8a1749f1c3
Mismatching
```

I've also create a github issue on Parity Repo.
https://github.com/paritytech/parity-ethereum/issues/11318

I have tried to find similar issues, #8841. The only difference I see that nonce and mixHash isn't present for PoA chains. It is intuitive that nonce is not present as there is no mining involved and so the mixHash. Nonce(at index 14) and mixHash(at index 13) is taken as null by the eth-object library (we can see last two items in the block header array) which generates a 15 length Buffer Array representing the block header (which is to be RLP encoded further and hashed).

So how exactly the block hash of the PoA chain block `0x41055969db3b40fd07ef1374353c051f9f24f3aff806186b1e9d134f01d8467a` got generated by parity?